# Not understanding arc midpoint computation

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm trying to find the midpoint of an arc, so I [found](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96168/how-to-find-mid-point-of-an-arc) this [page](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/RR/database/RR.09.10/akulov2.html) wherein Gregory V. Akulov and Oleksandr G. Akulov describe the midpoint formula. I pasted the formula & description from the site below.

> Let origin-centered arc of radius r have the ends at
> x=a,b, and midpoint at x=μ. Then
>
> [image: formula]
> where the first radical gets “−” iff the arc has a negative x-intercept, and
> the second radical gets “+” iff  the arc  has a positive x-intercept.

The site poses a example question, also pasted below:

> Origin-centered arc of radius 50,   located as shown at Figure 2, has the ends at x=14 and x=25. Find x-coordinate of its midpoint.

I tried to solve it, but it seems I went off the rails somewhere.

```
2μ = ±sqrt((50+14)(50+25)) ±sqrt((50-14)(50-25))
            ↓                          ↓
     ±sqrt(64*75) = ±sqrt(4,800)       ↓
                           ±sqrt(36*25) = ±sqrt(900)
                          
2μ = -sqrt(4,800) +sqrt(900) //x intercept is positive, so both radicals get "+"
μ  = 39.282
```

But the answer I *should* have gotten was:

> r=50,a=14,b=25, both radicals go with “+”, and 20sqrt(3+15) is the
> answer;

I haven't taken Trigonometry yet, so maybe that's part of the problem. But **this isn't homework**, it's something I'm trying to figure out to further a project of my own. There isn't anybody I can ask right now, so I was wondering if someone here could correct my mistake?

Comment: If you know both radicals are positive, why did you make the first one negative?

Comment: It may be helpful to try a simple test case. For example, take the two points to have the same $x$-coordinate but opposite $y$-coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was just in computation. 
In your answer you put a negative for the first radical (if it is not a typo).

So we can calculate it again as 
\begin{gather}
\mu =\frac{\sqrt{4800}+ \sqrt{900}}{2}
\end{gather}
Since $\sqrt{4}= 2$ we can replace it here
\begin{gather}
\mu = \frac{\sqrt{4800} + \sqrt {900}}{\sqrt{4}}
\end{gather}
We can seperate the fraction and then join radicals since $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}} = \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$
\begin{gather}
\mu = \frac{\sqrt{4800}}{{\sqrt4}} + \frac{\sqrt {900}}{\sqrt{4}}
\\\\
\mu = \sqrt{\frac{4800}{4}} + \sqrt{\frac{900}{4}}
\end{gather}
Now these both divide nicely
\begin{gather}
\mu = \sqrt{1200} + \sqrt{225}
\end{gather}
Now the square root of 225 is a nice 15, and 1200 can be written as it's factors $\sqrt{400*3}$ since 400 has a nice root as well. Since $\sqrt{a*b}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ we can calculate this as well
\begin{gather}
\mu = \sqrt{400}\sqrt{3} + 15
\\\\
\mu = 20\sqrt{3} + 15
\end{gather}

Here the radical only extends over the three, it does not include 15. I hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: Oh you are right. The… man I must be tired. That being said part of the problem is I'm perhaps a little under-confident in my math skills :\. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm impressed you are doing this by yourself to begin with! Keep it up man, you're doing well.